# How to invert a text in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Can anyone post a simple example of inverting a `Text` placed inside a `Container`.

Here is the starting code.

```
Widget _myWidget() {
  return Container(
    height: 100.0,
    color: Colors.orange,
    child: Center(child: Text("GO", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 70.0)),),
  );
}
```

Above code shows following output:

[image]

What I want it to look like is :

[image]

Comment: [Transform](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html)

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it works super weird. Can you please post code starting from my own. I remember you answering my question os scaleX and scaleY using Transform and there I used y = -1.0, but it takes the view out of the screen too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the code to do that

```
    import 'dart:math';
    class FlipedText extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Material(
        child: Transform(
          transform:Matrix4.rotationX(pi),
          alignment: Alignment.center,

          child: Container(
            height: 100.0,
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Center(child: Text("GO", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 70.0)),),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)